# Recursive Function practice

Tags: c++, c++11, recursion

I am studying for an upcoming exam and one of the questions on the study guide is:

Write a recursive C++ function for converting a string of digits into the integer it represents. For
example, “13531” represents the integer 13531. Your function should return the integer value.

I am able to convert the string to an integer but am having trouble on what the base case should be for the function to be recursive. Any suggestions or help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to post an answer?

Comment: If you show us what your recursive case looks like, we can show you what the base case looks like.

Answer (score 2):

The base case is an empty string.

Each step of your recursion converts one character in the string to an integer. And the recursive step passes in the remainder of the string.

Comment: Best way to deal with homework questions. Provide ideas, not code. :-)

Answer (score 0):

As yourself how you might "work your way" through the starting string?

My gut feel tells me from "1357" I would would start with "7", leaving "135", then "5", leaving "13", and so on. And what are you eventually left with? An empty string!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether you mean 'edge case' by 'base case'.

The edge case should be one that doesn't need any recursion any more and thus can be worked out directly. Thus it can be when the 'string' has only one digit (`return str[0]-'0';`) or has zero digit (`return 0;`) I think. The zero digit case might be a little more general.

Just a little more about the 'base' of the number if it could be other than base-10 number.

> You might have to test the base of the number first. For c++11,
>   decimal-literal (base 10), octal-literal (base 8) and hex-literal
>   (base 16) are supported, e.g. -0x123, -0123, -123. You can do
>   the test according to [cpp_integer_literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal).

Comment: Sorry, misunderstand what `base` refers to.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;
int convert(string x)
{
int c=x[0]-'0';//to get the numeric value of the first char in string
if(x.size()==1)//base case
    return c;
//in each time return the char with "x.size()-1" digits of zero and the first digit is for the number
return c*pow(10,x.size()-1)+convert(x.substr(1));
}
int main(){
string x;
getline(cin,x);
cout<<convert(x);
}
```

"12345" will be returned as no=10000+2000+300+40+5

Answer (score 0):

What about without any usage of `pow`, like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int str_to_int(const std::string& str)
{
    if (str.size() == 0)
        return 0; // base case, end recursion
    else
        return (str[str.size() - 1] - '0') +
               10 * str_to_int(str.substr(0, str.size() - 1));
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << str_to_int("1234");
}
```

Comment: That one is horribly inefficient since it creates lots of string objects during recursion. OK, no-one asked about efficiency :-)

Answer (score 0):

tailed recursion edition

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
void str2int(const std::string& s, int &result, int n = 0)
{
    if (n == s.size())
    {
        return;
    }

    result *= 10;
    result += s[n] - '0';
    return str2int(s, result, n + 1);
}

int main()
{
    int n = 0;

    str2int("1234", n);

    std::cout << n;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using iterators seems to be more elegant and has the advantage that the conversion function can be applied on sub-strings.

```
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int str2int(string::const_iterator s, string::const_iterator e)
{
   if(s==e) return 0;
   --e;
   return str2int(s,e)*10+*e-'0'; 
}

int main()
{
   string s="12345";
   printf("%d\n",str2int(s.begin(),s.end()));
}
```